# Koa cookie returning `undefined`

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, koa, koa-router

After a POST request is sent from the browser to the `/generate` url in the server, I want to create a string and save it as a cookie. When a GET request is later sent from the browser to the `/retrieve` url in the server, I want to send that string as a response to the client.

Here is what I tried:

**routes.js**

```
const Router = require('koa-router')
const router = new Router()

router.post('/generate', function * () {
  this.cookies.set('generatedString', 'example')
  this.response.body = 'String saved as cookie!'
})

router.get('/retrieve', function * () {
  const cookie = this.cookies.get('generatedString')
  console.log(cookie) // undefined!
  this.response.body = cookie
})
```

Why does doing `this.cookies.get('generatedString')` return `undefined` even though the POST request handler has already run and should have `set` that cookie? Any help would be appreciated!

---

**EDIT:** In case it is of importance, I thought it would be worth mentioning that I am using the `fetch` API to make the POST and GET requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In case it is of importance, I thought it would be worth mentioning that I am using the fetch API to make the POST and GET requests.

The [`fetch` API](https://github.com/github/fetch#caveats) mentions that "By default, fetch won't send any cookies to the server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session."

If you want `fetch` to send cookies, you will need to add an option to the request you send out called `credentials` and set it to a value of `include`.

Example POST request:

```
const request = {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: ...,
  body: ...
}

fetch('/generate', request).then(...)
```

Example GET request:

```
fetch('/retrieve', { credentials: 'include' }).then(...)
```